# How can I check Who is mentioned | Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

`if user.id == "878176818564317184":`
`ctx.send("Trying to rickroll me")`

I tried this but isn't working
i want to check if the user has used the function on the bot or another member

Comment: you get a message and you want to see who is mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Id's are `ints`, not `strings`, so your `if-statement` will never be true (as an `int` is never equal to a `string`). Remove the `"` quotes around the id.

```py
if user.id == 878176818564317184:
```

Assuming the `user` variable is already an instance of `discord.User` or `discord.Member`. The code in your question doesn't show where `user` comes from or what it is, so I assume it's an argument of a command that you used a `Converter` on.

Comment: @VirajLOng if it helped then you should accept my answer